# Getting Error on Publish the Azure Application

Tags: azure

When i am trying to make package of cloud application code my visual studio is getting restart.I am unable to make a package,please suggest me solution ASAP.

Comment: please provide more details. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272%28VS.80%29.aspx or run msbuild manually to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Please explain what kind of project you're using, the error you're getting, anything special you're using, ... and don't use ASAP in your question (or get support from Microsoft here: https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Visual Studio crashes when you build a Windows Azure application, please try to reinstall the Windows Azure tools. Moreover, you can also use CSPack to manually create the package. I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432988.aspx for more information.

In addition, if the issue is still encountered, please provide more information as other communities point out, then we can find the issue more conveniently and provide further suggestions for you.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.